# php strtr equivalent in java

Tags: java

Is there a function in Java which is equivalent to php's `strtr`?

```
string strtr ( string $str , string $from , string $to )
```

If given three arguments, `strtr` function returns a copy of string where all occurrences of each (single-byte) character in `$from` have been translated to the corresponding character in `$to`, i.e., every occurrence of `$from[$n]` has been replaced with `$to[$n]`, where `$n` is a valid offset in both arguments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cannot find a direct equivalence to your `strtr` in the JDK. In Apache Commons StringUtils, there is [StringUtils.replaceChars](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#replaceChars-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)

[String.replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29) Does not really fit your case, unless you use it for each letter in your `$from` argument and replace it with the `$to` substitute. It's pretty easy to implement your own utility function using StringBuilder and replacing it yourself, though. Which is pretty much what StringUtils.replace does.

Answer (score 2):

You can call `String.replace(char oldChar, char newChar)` in a cycle. For example:

```
String from = "abc";
String   to = "xyz";
String str = "abc string";
for( int i = 0; i < from.length(); i++ )
  str = str.replace(from.charAt(i), to.charAt(i));
```

Comment: this is O(n m), where n is the size of the string and m is the number of character replacements

Answer (score 2):

Wrote the following two methods, since I was looking for something similar to the strtr functionality. Just copy and paste this code in your java project and use the two methods provided (Apache License 2.0):

## Example Usage

```
Map<String, String> replacements = new TreeMap<String, String>();
replacements.put("this", "that");
replacements.put("that", "this");
replacements.put("Nothing much", "Everything");

String example = Strtr.replaceStringUsingMap("Whether this or that, whats the difference? Nothing much.", replacements);

System.out.println(example);
```

## Output

Input String:

```
"Whether this or that, whats the difference? Nothing much."
```

Output String:

```
"Whether that or this, whats the difference? Everything."
```

## Source Code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeMap;

/**
 * Two public methods can be used, mimicing strtr in php:
 * 
 * {@link #replaceStringUsingChars(String, String, String)}
 * 
 * {@link #replaceStringUsingMap(String, Map)}

 * Apache 2.0 License
 * 
 * @author Basil Musa
 */
public class Strtr {

    /**
     * Similar to strtr in php, characters in 'from' will be replaced by characters in 'to'
     * in the same order character by character.
     * 
     * @param haystack
     * @param from
     * @param to
     * @return String having the replacements made
     */
    public static String replaceStringUsingChars(String haystack, String from, String to) {
        if (from.length() != to.length()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("from and to should have same number of characters.");
        }
        Map<String, String> replacements = new HashMap<String, String>();
        int length = from.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            replacements.put(String.valueOf(from.charAt(i)), String.valueOf(to.charAt(i)));
        }
        return replaceStringUsingMap(haystack, replacements);
    }

    /**
     * This method will return a string by replacing all occurrences of keys in needle2replacement occurring in
     * haystack with the corresponding values. Once a replacement is made, it wont be replaced again.
     * 
     * The method will start with the longest keys first.
     * Keys of "" (empty strings) will be ignored.
     * 
     * If the map is empty, the method returns the same haystack String directly.
     * 
     * @param haystack The string to be replaced
     * @param needle2replacement The map of keys to search and values to be replaced
     * @return String containing haystack with all the replacements in needle2replacement made
     */
    public static String replaceStringUsingMap(String haystack, Map<String, String> needle2replacement)
    {
        // To optimize, just return the haystack if the map has no items
        if (needle2replacement.isEmpty()) {
            return haystack;
        }

        // Sort map by length of keys please by longest string first
        Map<String, String> sortedNeedle2replacement = sortKeysByLengthDescending(needle2replacement);

        Set<String> arrNeedles = sortedNeedle2replacement.keySet();
        List<Range> ranges = new ArrayList<>();

        int lengthDifference = 0;
        for (String needle : arrNeedles) {

            int indexOf = -1;

            // Ignore needles whom are empty strings
            if (needle.equals("")) {
                continue;
            }

            while(-1 != (indexOf = haystack.indexOf(needle, indexOf + 1))) {
                String replacement = sortedNeedle2replacement.get(needle);
                if (replacement == null) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Map value of null found in key ['" + needle + "']");
                }

                Range range = new Range(indexOf, indexOf + needle.length() - 1, needle, replacement);

                // Check for any overlaps
                boolean addRange = true;
                for (Range target : ranges) {
                    if (range.isOverlappingWith(target)) {
                        addRange = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (addRange) {
                    ranges.add(range);
                    lengthDifference += range.replacement.length() - range.needle.length();
                }
            }
        }

        // Sort ranges please
        Collections.sort(ranges, new Comparator<Range>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Range o1, Range o2) {
                return o1.begin - o2.begin;
            }
        });

        // type them
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(haystack.length() + lengthDifference);

        int startAt = 0;
        for (Range range : ranges) {
            stringBuilder.append(haystack.substring(startAt, range.begin));
            stringBuilder.append(range.replacement);
            startAt = range.end + 1;
        }
        stringBuilder.append(haystack.substring(startAt));

        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    private static class Range
    {
        public Range(int begin, int end, String needle, String replacement) {
            super();
            if (begin > end) {
                throw new RuntimeException("begin [" + begin + "] should be smaller or equal to end [" + end + "]");
            }
            this.begin = begin;
            this.end = end;
            this.needle = needle;
            this.replacement = replacement;
        }

        public final int begin;
        public final int end;
        public final String needle;
        public final String replacement;

        public String toString() {
            return String.format("{%d,%d,%s,%s}", begin, end, needle, replacement);
        }

        /**
         * @param target
         * @return
         */
        public boolean isOverlappingWith(Range target) {
            final boolean liesBefore = this.end < target.begin;
            final boolean liesAfter = this.begin > target.end;
            if (liesBefore || liesAfter) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        /**
         * +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
         *             XXXXXX
         *          YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
         *          
         * Y is surround X as shown above
         * 
         * @param target
         * @return
         */
        public boolean isSurrounding(Range target) {
            if (this.begin < target.begin && this.end > target.end) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }


    private static Map<String, String> sortKeysByLengthDescending(
            Map<String, String> needle2replacement) {
        Map<String, String> sortedNeedle2replacement = new TreeMap<String, String>(new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
                if (s1.length() > s2.length()) {
                    return -1;
                } else if (s1.length() < s2.length()) {
                    return 1;
                } else {
                    return s1.compareTo(s2);
                }
            }
        });
        sortedNeedle2replacement.putAll(needle2replacement);

        return sortedNeedle2replacement;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an implementation I wrote before. You're welcome to it.

```
public static String strtr(String str, String from, String to) {
    char[] out = null;
    for (int i = 0, len = str.length(); i < len; i++) {
        char c = str.charAt(i);
        int p = from.indexOf(c);
        if (p >= 0) {
            if (out == null) out = str.toCharArray();
            out[i] = to.charAt(p);
        }
    }
    return out != null ? new String(out) : str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My method:

```
public static String strtr(String str, String froms, String tos) { 

      char[] str1 = str.toCharArray();

      for (int i=0,len=str.length(); i<len; ++i){
          int j = froms.indexOf(str.charAt(i));
          if (j != -1)
             str1[i]=tos.charAt(j);

      return String.valueOf(str1);
 }
```