# Need to replace every letter of inputed text with another specific letter

Tags: java, string, str-replace

I need to create program that takes the originalText and replaces each letter in the originalText with a new specific letter then prints it out as mixedLetterText.

This is what I have but it only works for the first "String mixedLetterText=originalText.replace('a', 'w');" and doesn't change any of the other letter. I am very new to all of this and just don't know what is wrong... anyway thanks! Please help.

```
public class MixLettersAndNumbers
{

    public static void main(String[] args)

    {
        String originalText = "as we walk";


        String mixedLetterText = 
        originalText.replace('a', 'w');
        originalText.replace('s', 'e');
        originalText.replace('d', 'r');
        originalText.replace('f', 't');
        originalText.replace('g', 'y');
        originalText.replace('h', 'u');
        originalText.replace('j', 'i');
        originalText.replace('k', 'o');
        originalText.replace('l', 'p');
        originalText.replace('z', 's');
        originalText.replace('x', 'd');
        originalText.replace('c', 'f');
        originalText.replace('v', 'g');
        originalText.replace('b', 'h');
        originalText.replace('n', 'j');
        originalText.replace('m', 'k');   
        originalText.replace('q', '1');
        originalText.replace('w', '2');
        originalText.replace('e', '3');
        originalText.replace('r', '4');
        originalText.replace('t', '5');
        originalText.replace('y', '6');
        originalText.replace('u', '7');
        originalText.replace('i', '8');
        originalText.replace('o', '9');
        originalText.replace('p', '0');

        //test it out
        System.out.println("original = " + originalText);
        System.out.println("mixed = " + mixedLetterText);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible this is mistagged? looks like Java not javascript.

Comment: Agree, this is not JavaScript. I'm not familiar with Java, but it seems that you would have to put `String mixedLetterText = ` before every replace statement. Although I'm sure someone's got a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

Replace all (similar) lines from:

```
originalText.replace('h', 'u');
```

to:

```
originalText = originalText.replace('h', 'u');
```

The `replace()` function will return a modified version of text.

At last, the variable `originalText` will contain modified version of the text.

That is to say,

```
// no need to use mixedLetterText if you are not intended to keep originalText
originalText = originalText.replace('a', 'w');
originalText = originalText.replace('s', 'e');
originalText = originalText.replace('d', 'r');
originalText = originalText.replace('f', 't');
originalText = originalText.replace('g', 'y');
```

... and so on

Comment: this did work but @kolink was still right that some of them don't work because they repeat. Is there a quick fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

Is this Java or JavaScript? Java is to JavaScript as ham is to hamster.

Anyway, your code literally says "assign the first replacement to `mixedLetterText`, then compute all the other replacements one by one and throw them away".

Depending on how you want it to work, you can either just chain the replacements:

```
String mixedLetterText = originalText
       .replace('a','w').replace('s','e')........
```

However, keep in mind that if you have crossovers, you might have issues. For example, with your code in a chain, if the input is `g` then the output will be `6`, not `y` like you might expect.

If you are working in Java, then [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532957/php-strtr-equivalent-in-java) will help find a function to do the conversion. If it is Java*Script*, then [this function](http://phpjs.org/functions/strtr/) will help.

Comment: you are correct... g does print 6 not y. any way to quick fix that?

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are just trying to change the original text once.
Make these changes

```
String  mixedLetterText=originalText.replace('s', 'e');
mixedLetterText=originalText.replace('d', 'r');
mixedLetterText=originalText.replace('f', 't');
mixedLetterText=originalText.replace('g', 'y');
mixedLetterText=originalText.replace('h', 'u');
mixedLetterText=originalText.replace('j', 'i');
mixedLetterText=originalText.replace('k', 'o');
mixedLetterText= originalText.replace('l', 'p');
mixedLetterText=originalText.replace('z', 's');
mixedLetterText=originalText.replace('x', 'd');
mixedLetterText=originalText.replace('c', 'f');
mixedLetterText=originalText.replace('v', 'g');
mixedLetterText=originalText.replace('b', 'h');
mixedLetterText=originalText.replace('n', 'j');
mixedLetterText=originalText.replace('m', 'k');   
mixedLetterText=originalText.replace('q', '1');
mixedLetterText=originalText.replace('w', '2');
mixedLetterText=originalText.replace('e', '3');
mixedLetterText=originalText.replace('r', '4');
mixedLetterText=originalText.replace('t', '5');
mixedLetterText=originalText.replace('y', '6');
mixedLetterText=originalText.replace('u', '7');
mixedLetterText=originalText.replace('i', '8');
mixedLetterText=originalText.replace('o', '9');
mixedLetterText=originalText.replace('p', '0');
```

Comment: yeah you are correct I forget to assign it again to the same string